# Spec2 unit test is not compiling

Tags: unit-testing, scala, specs2

I've written a median function and want to add some unit tests for it.

So I wrote this in specs2

```
class TestStats extends Specification {
  "Median function " should {
    "be None for an empty list" in { Stats.median([]) must beNone }
    "be the midpoint of an odd length list" in { Stats.median([1,2,3]) must_== Some(2)}
    "be the average of the two midpoints of an even length list" in { Stats.median([1,2,3,4])     must_== Some(2.5)}
  }
}
```

However, it doesn't compile with the error `No implicit view available from Option[Double] => org.specs2.execute.Result.` on the `"be None...` line.

I don't understand why it's asking for this in here. Am I really supposed to write an implicit myself to do this comparison?

*Edit* So the issue was purely syntactical - see my answer below. I'm a little annoyed that a syntax error was reported to me as a semantic error, which is why it never occurred to me that my list literals were wrong.

Comment: Could you please show more code (including imports)? And what is []? On a first glance your test looks correct.

Comment: `[]`, `[1,2,3]` and `[1,2,3,4]` are invalid Scala code.

Comment: Also, what's the type signature of `Stats.median`?

Comment: It was a purely syntactic issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly, I've spent too long doing Python recently. 
Correcting the list literal syntax fixes the issue:

```
class TestStats extends Specification {
  "Median function " should {
    "be None for an empty list" in { median(Nil) must_== None }
    "be the midpoint of an odd length list" in { median(List(1, 2, 3)) must_== Some(2) }
    "be the average of the two midpoints of an even length list" in { median(List(1, 2, 3, 4)) must_== Some(2.5) }
  }
}
```

Comment: Did it even compile with your other list (python?) syntax?

Comment: No, I was asking why it wouldn't compile

Comment: I meant, I would have expected a different compiler error than you got :-)